# Is Rimmer's Salute Regulation?

Tags: red-dwarf

Rimmer has shall we say a... [unique salute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al5bErqFrDQ) when addressing officers he wants to impress. However I've never seen any other member of the crew salute with anything more than our much more traditional one.

Is the salute a massively over-embellished version of a standard JMC one (should all officers salute's start out in front in the way his does?) or has he just made the entire thing up to impress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it was not standard.

Rimmer hoped that his salute would become the JMC standard, as described [here](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/guide/index.cfm?sectionID=behind-the-scenes&seriesID=1&subsectionID=writing).

In the very first episode of Red Dwarf, other crew members use a more traditional salute when addressing the Captain.

Comment: We actually see Rimmer lobbying for the salute to become the standard JMC salute in "Ouroboros".